# Insert (submit) data from HTML form into MySqli database by php 5.5

Tags: phpmyadmin, php

У меня не получается внести данные из HTML в mysql-таблице.

Есть два файла: HTML-файл, в котором я сделал форму из трёх текстовых полей и кнопки submit, и  php-файл, по которому я устанавливаю связь с базой данных и посредством INSERT INTO пытаюсь добавить строку в таблице.

Вот код php:

```
<?php

echo "Hello World";

$connection = new mysqli('localhost' , 'root' ,'','accounts') or die("problem");

$valueFirst = $_POST['First'];
$valueLast = $_POST['Last'];
$valueKey = $_POST['Keywords'];

$imsql = "INSERT INTO users (First,Last,Keywords) VALUES ('$valueFirst', '$valueLast', '$valueKey') ";

echo "Hello 777";

?>
```

Соединение работает, но данные не добавляются.

Как сделать так, чтобы машина понимала, от каких полей брать данные. Как связать HTML-форму с php-кодом?

Если можно, напишите примеры кодов.

Comment: Примеры, пожалуйста, по mysqli.  
Заранее благодарю)

Comment: HTML-код покажите. Ну и как бы где тут добавление данных в БД-то? 
    if ($res = $connection->query($imsql)) {
    echo "OK";
    $connection->close();
    }
    

Answer (score 1):

Не факт, что Вы верно посылаете данные из формы. Но в целом выглядеть должно примерно так

```
<?php

echo "Hello World";

$connection = new mysqli('localhost' , 'root' ,'','accounts') or die("problem");

$valueFirst = $_POST['First'];
$valueLast = $_POST['Last'];
$valueKey = $_POST['Keywords'];

$imsql = "INSERT INTO users (First,Last,Keywords) VALUES ('$valueFirst', '$valueLast', '$valueKey') ";

if ($res = $connection->query($imsql)) {
    echo "OK";
}else{
    printf("Error %s\n", $connection->error);
}
$connection->close();
?>
```